# Text labeling with machine learning

Tags: java, machine-learning, clojure, text-classification

I want to label a bunch of bank transactions according to a set of predefined classes (example below, its a map in `clojure`). I tried a naive bayes approach but sometimes it totally gives me the wrong label.

According to my research, I should use a supervised ML algorithm, something like a linear SVM tuned for multiclass classification. Problem is I don't know anything about ML really. Second problem is that most clojure libs are outdated.

```
{:label "5339134-17-CPR-FARMODISSEIA LD", :value -13271 :class :health}
{:label "PAG.SERV. 10297 779747511", :value -2889 :class :utilities}
{:label "5339134-14-CPR-GREEN PEPER", :value -1785 :class :restaurants}
{:label "5339134-03-LEV-Av Alm Kings", :value -4000 :class :atm}
{:label "5339134-02-LEV-Big Field, 1", :value -7000 :class :atm}
{:label "IMPOSTO DE SELO", :value -17 :class :banking}
```

So most of the similar transactions have like 90% similar text (see eg: `:atm`), I believe this should be an easy problem.

My questions:

- what algorithms can I use?
- how should I prepare the data? I believe I only have two features, tx label and tx value. Some tutorials I see have a bunch of vectors, but I don't know if/how to convert the string data to the proper ML format.

Any sample in either clj or java will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a larger example dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said in your question that

> most of the similar transactions have like 90% similar text

I thought it would make sense to first figure out which transaction labels are similar to each other and group them together. Then you have a limited number of groups, and the group that each label falls into can be used as a nominal attribute in place of the text itself. If transactions in the same class have similar label text, then hopefully this should allow the classification algorithm to easily draw correlations between label and class.

I tried implementing a solution using these dependencies:

```clj
[[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
 [clj-fuzzy "0.4.0"]
 [cc.artifice/clj-ml "0.8.5"]
 [rm-hull/clustering "0.1.3"]]
```

After clustering the labels, the naïve Bayes approach seemed to work fine for me:

```clj
(require '[clj-fuzzy.metrics :as fm]
         '[clj-ml.classifiers :as classify]
         '[clj-ml.data :as data]
         '[clustering.core.qt :as qt])

(def data
  [{:label "5339134-17-CPR-FARMODISSEIA LD", :value -13271 :class :health}
   {:label "PAG.SERV. 10297 779747511", :value -2889 :class :utilities}
   {:label "5339134-14-CPR-GREEN PEPER", :value -1785 :class :restaurants}
   {:label "5339134-03-LEV-Av Alm Kings", :value -4000 :class :atm}
   {:label "5339134-02-LEV-Big Field, 1", :value -7000 :class :atm}
   {:label "IMPOSTO DE SELO", :value -17 :class :banking}])

(def clusters
  (into {}
        (for [cluster (qt/cluster fm/levenshtein (map :label data) 13 1)
              s cluster]
          [s (keyword (str "cluster" (hash cluster)))])))

(def dataset
  (-> (data/make-dataset "my-data"
                         [:value
                          {:label (seq (set (vals clusters)))}
                          {:class [:health :utilities :restaurants :atm :banking]}]
                         (map (juxt :value (comp clusters :label) :class) data))
      (data/dataset-set-class :class)))

(def data-map
  (let [m (into {} (map (juxt data/instance-to-map identity)
                        (data/dataset-seq dataset)))]
    (into {} (for [x data]
               [x (-> x (update :label clusters) (update :value double) m)]))))

(def classifier
  (-> (classify/make-classifier :bayes :naive)
      (classify/classifier-train dataset)))

(defn foo []
  (for [x data]
     (->> x
          data-map
          data/instance-set-class-missing
          (classify/classifier-classify classifier)
          (assoc x :predicted))))

(run! prn (foo))
;; {:label "5339134-17-CPR-FARMODISSEIA LD", :value -13271, :class :health, :predicted :health}
;; {:label "PAG.SERV. 10297 779747511", :value -2889, :class :utilities, :predicted :utilities}
;; {:label "5339134-14-CPR-GREEN PEPER", :value -1785, :class :restaurants, :predicted :restaurants}
;; {:label "5339134-03-LEV-Av Alm Kings", :value -4000, :class :atm, :predicted :atm}
;; {:label "5339134-02-LEV-Big Field, 1", :value -7000, :class :atm, :predicted :atm}
;; {:label "IMPOSTO DE SELO", :value -17, :class :banking, :predicted :banking}
```

I'm quite new to ML though, so please let me know if there's something I've overlooked.

Also, in my implementation, I use QT clustering to do a one-time partition of the labels in the input dataset, but if the goal is to continue incorporating new data over time, it may be necessary to use a streaming clustering algorithm instead. It looks like this may be possible with k-means, but that would require implementation of a "Levenshtein averaging" function. In addition, I'm not sure if the clustering library I'm using supports iteration upon its initial result, so further implementation may be necessary.

Comment: Its looking great. Can you explain the rationale? Why you have to do clustering? Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelPing I've added my rationale and some other comments to my answer. Let me know if there's anything else you'd like me to add!

Comment: Sure, I was running the code and I dunno how can I classify a new instance, if I supply eg; a `{:label "xxxx" :value -123}` how can I get the predicted class? Also, I switched levensthein for jaccard, I believe it is much faster.

Comment: @MiguelPing You could construct a [BK-tree](https://github.com/mishok13/bktree.clj) of the labels you've seen so far and use it to implement a `find-cluster` function to map labels to clusters, then call `(classify/classifier-classify classifier (data/make-instance dataset (update {:label "xxxx" :value -123} :label find-cluster)))` to classify your instance. I can try to write up an implementation of that `find-cluster` function if you'd like.

Comment: BK-trees look cool. I ended up implementing a rudimentar string clean function to remove numbers and such, so clustering becomes much easier. If you can provide a more data-science oriented `find-cluster` that would be great, I'm always on the go for learning.

Comment: @SamEstep would love to see that. I'm also using this for some basic personal accounting classification and I think it would be a great help to a lot of people :)

Comment: @PetrusTheron I haven't looked at this for a while, but I'll see what I can do!

Comment: I don't understand how to classify new data. How do I choose an appropriate cluster or label for a new data point?

Comment: Aside: `(comp clusters :label)` won't work for a cluster-set, only a single value. Instead: (defn s->cluster [clusters x]
  (when (seq clusters)
    (or ((fn [[the-set cluster] x]
           (if (get the-set x) cluster)) (first clusters) x)
        (recur (next clusters) x))))

Comment: @PetrusTheron I haven't forgotten about this (I have it on my todo list), but I want to make sure when I revamp my answer that I can do a satisfactory job. I realize that you aren't the original asker, but would it be possible for you to put together a larger dataset that I could then use to test my work? As it is, I have no way of knowing whether my solution is effective.